# PyAutoGui Nan NaN NaN

Tags: python, pyautogui

`pyautogui.displayMousePosition()` displays `848 Y:  853 RGB: (NaN, NaN, NaN)`

I am not sure why it will not pick up RGB colors. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by: "...find the color values."

Comment: @GGberry the RGB numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `sys.platform == "darwin"` returns False. As you can see in PyAutoGui's python file:

```
if not onScreen(x - xOffset, y - yOffset) or sys.platform == "darwin":
    # Pixel color can only be found for the primary monitor, and also not on mac due to the screenshot having the mouse cursor in the way.
    pixelColor = ("NaN", "NaN", "NaN")
```

if `sys.platform` returns "darwin", it's normal for you to get `RGB: (NaN, NaN, NaN)` as result.

To fix this problem, you can simply do:

```
import sys

sys.platform = '_' # sys.platform is no longer "darwin"
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```